# Trying To Read Friends Links in Facebook Using FQL: Why do some friends return an empty set?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

When trying to find friends of mine that also use this app and have links from a specific site, I'm getting no results from some friends, but it works great on others. If I use the Graph API Explorer, doing something as simple as /friendid/links returns an empty set. However, I can go to their wall and see links and they have the read_stream permissions granted to my app.

Of note, they appear to have a different Privacy Settings experience as well (completely different set of screens).

Anyone ever seen this?  How can Facebook be granted permissions, but not really get them?

Comment: You need an access token and "read_stream" permission if the link is not public.

Comment: FYI, I filed a bug with Facebook and its been confirmed: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/166799263418256?browse=search_4f593bba397328586301645

Answer (score 2):

It's all to do with the privacy settings of the friend you are trying to access data about. Facebook allows you to set different levels of data that will be shared with apps that have been installed by your friends. By default, the privacy setting is ticked for "My Links", but I imagine that a LOT of people, including me, will have turned this off.

[image: Screenshot of the permissions screen]

Comment: I also just provided a comprehensive list of steps to perform to prove this is the case, but for some reason the 2nd answer has gone. I am not spending another 15 minutes of my life repeating myself.

Comment: @BeaverProj, the original poster said Facebook has confirmed this is a bug. Dont know who is right....

Comment: I think the Facebook staff member who confirmed it as a bug is wrong, and it will be played out as such in that bug report. My exhaustive removed reply proved it was working as intended.

Comment: OK, I can do some investigation and see if this fixes the issue.