# Why are my results different from using FB website and FB API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Seemingly simple question but I found no obvious answer so far.

I logon to Facebook.com using my browser. I go to the search bar, type in 'Obama'. Then Select 'Public Posts' on the left hand side bar, which starts listing all PUBLIC posts. I pick up one of the posts that shares a like/photo and has a URL like this : 'www.facebook/com/story_fbid=&id=. I figure out that abc is the user_id and xyz is the object_id. This also means that the post_id is abc_xyz.

Then I go to the graph.facebook.com API explorer, generate a user access token, then type this query:

> https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select post_id from stream where
>   post_id="abc_xyz"

NOTHING.

I even try

> select link_id from link where link_id in ("xyz", "abc_xyz")

still NOTHING.

So, What is happening here? Some posts on StackOverflow talk about how facebook's public posts are not truly public - BUT, there is no reference to this in the official FB documentation.

Then, I tried creating a new account, creating post on my wall, making my wall posts public, then I tried the same queries as above, and yet again NOTHING (just an empty dataset).

Guys, are there any official explanations to this behavior? When I am logged in as user, I AM NOT an APP!/ROBOT, but just an end user - I can see a public post/link/share/photo, then why on earth can the API not do the same? What can I do, to make a PUBLIC POST, MORE PUBLIC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer to this question answers my question: [Trying To Read Friends Links in Facebook Using FQL: Why do some friends return an empty set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222516/trying-to-read-friends-links-in-facebook-using-fql-why-do-some-friends-return-a)

Facebook's users are allowed to set separate permissions for apps, so even when I am using the graph api explorer (which is an app) or the api directly (which is equivalent to an app), any public links/photos are only available to these apps when the original author of these links/photos/status has NOT unchecked it from "**How people bring your info to the apps they use**" setting under privacy settings.

I experimented with a test fb account, shared a link (with the default privacy settings), and I was able to query it using FQL on the link table, and then, I turned off 'My Links' under privacy settings and this time the same query in api explorer returned empty set.

So, the answer to my question "What can I do, to make a PUBLIC POST, more PUBLIC" would be that **I can't do nothing about it** - it is a setting that the user who posted this public post controls. When it is at default, I'll have access to it, when its not, I won't.

Hope, this helps others looking for similar answers.